# Qué hacer cuando java no reconoce arrays

Tags: java, array

Aquí por ejemplo, no reconoce los arrays.

```
String [] titulos = (id,nombres,ap_Paterno,ap_Materno,sexo, direccion, email,fecha_Nacimiento);
```

Me gustaría que me ayudaran a solucionar cuál es la razón que no me deje utilizarlos así. Error:

> unbalanced read/write with arrays

Comment: Hola, Lila. Bienvenida a [stackoverflow en español](http://es.stackoverflow.con). Te recomiendo que antes de hacer una pregunta, sea la tecnología que sea, le eches primero un ojo a su documentación.

Answer (score 6):

Primero debes instanciar el array con la palabra reservada `new` para luego poder manipularlo. Además las cadenas en java se escriben entre `" "` su ejemplo quedaría así

```
String [] titulos = 
new String [] {"id","nombres", "ap_Paterno" ,"ap_Materno","seco","direccion", "email","fecha_Nacimiento"};
```

Estas son las formas de crear un array de String e instanciar

```
String[] myStringArray = new String[3];// maximo de elementos que se puede colocar en la matriz 3
String[] myStringArray = {"a","b","c"};
String[] myStringArray = new String[]{"a","b","c"};
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que  la segunda forma no funciona con sentencias de retorno `return {1,2,3}` da un error, mientras que `return new int[]{1,2,3}` funciona bien (suponiendo, por supuesto, que su función devuelve una matriz de enteros)

Comment: @TrujilloSilvaLilaYiseth por favor no pongas "gracias" en un comentario. En su lugar, es mejor [aceptar la respuesta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/427/227).

Answer (score -1):

En un array de Strings tienes que poner el `String` en `" "` para cada palabra y separarla entre comas , en caso de char es `' '`, ten en cuenta que si no escribes las dos comillas te subrallara en rojo el `Array` por que no reconocera que es un `String`, luego si quieres hacer un bucle con un `for` debes utilizar el `.length` para indicar el máximo de letras que deseas poner.

Espero que sea de ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Tú respuesta, más bien parece un comentario, que una respuesta tal cuál se espera en el sitio. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer].